# .NET 4.0 Installation failure on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, .net-4.5

I need to deploy an asp net mvc app that requires .net 4.5
I am trying to install .NET 4.0 and I am getting a fatal error at the end of the process:

This is the log:

```
OS Version = 6.0.6001, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Win2K8 - x86 Datacenter Edition Service Pack 1
CommandLine = H:\3b4bd74090bffcb407705182\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /ia64 /web
TimeZone = E. South America Daylight Time
Initial LCID = 1046
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup
Package Version = 4.0.30319
User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
Number of applicable items: 11
Exe (H:\3b4bd74090bffcb407705182\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
Exe (C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\Windows6.0-KB956250-v6001-x86.msu) failed with 0x1 - Incorrect function. .
Exe (H:\3b4bd74090bffcb407705182\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
MSI (C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\netfx_Core_x86.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_20121209_003156019-MSI_netfx_Core_x86.msi.txt
MSI (C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\netfx_Extended_x86.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_20121209_003156019-MSI_netfx_Extended_x86.msi.txt
Exe (H:\3b4bd74090bffcb407705182\SetupUtility.exe) failed with 0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation. .
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:34:55).
```

Is there any restriction to install .net 4 on windows server 2008?

Answer (score 3):

To install .NET 4.5, you should use the standalone installer,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

It is meaningless to troubleshoot .NET 4 installation error if you actually want .NET 4.5.